# jQuery didn't run by using php include

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing a problem of jQuery in `index.php` not running when i include the file `header.php`. The nav sidebar were included but when i press the chevron, nothing happened? It only worked if i include `header_user.php` directly without checking the `UserType` in `header.php`. I cant just include `header_user.php` directly since i need the page to be displayed based on the `UserType`. In this code, assume that the current `UserType` is a `USER`. Please help. I don't know what is the problem.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'session.php';
    require_once 'connection.php';
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Nav Sidebar</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script>
    var change = true;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function () {
            $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });

    function toggle_caret() {
        $("#caret1").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down", change);
        $("#caret1").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-left", !change);
        change = !change
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php include 'header/header.php'; ?>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**header.php**

```
<?php

    $UType = $_SESSION['UserType'];

    $tsql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[LOGIN] WHERE UserType='$UType'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($UType == "USER")
        {
            include 'header_user.php';
        }
        else if ($UType == "SUPERIOR")
        {
            include 'header_superior.php';
        }
        else if ($UType == "ADMIN")
        {
            include 'header_admin.php';
        }
        else 
        die("Not a Valid User Type.");
    }
?>
```

**header_user.php**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Dashboard<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="toggle_caret()"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Requisition<small><span style="float:right" id="caret1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></small></a>
                </li>
                <ul class="nav collapse" id="sub1">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Form</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Status</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Approved</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Rejected</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;In Process</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**EDIT**

I've found that after i changed the query as below, the jQuery worked. Can somebody explain why it happened?

**header.php**

```
<?php

    $UType = $_SESSION['UserType'];

        if($UType == "USER")
        {
            include 'header_user.php';
        }
        else if ($UType == "SUPERIOR")
        {
            include 'header_superior.php';
        }
        else if ($UType == "ADMIN")
        {
            include 'header_admin.php';
        }
        else 
        die("Not a Valid User Type.");
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the UserType session variable is properly set and that the script isn't just closing at the call to die() in header.php? Try replacing die() with echo and see what happens.

Comment: @Paul yes. No problem with the session. I've tried to include the files directly instead of `header.php` to `header_user.php` and jQuery worked. So there's nothing wrong with sessions.

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't test what I'm asking... Just for the sake of argument, try either replacing die() with echo, or insert `$UType = "USER";` right AFTER `$UType = $_SESSION['UserType'];`.

Comment: @Paul I've updated. Please take a look

Comment: Check your browser's source code.

Comment: It worked now. I mean the chevron and all. But can somebody tell me what triggers jQuery not to work?

Comment: It clearly has to do with your database query. What is it supposed to be doing? You have your conditional block in a while() loop, but $row is never referenced. Are you just checking to see if a record is returned? I don't have access to your database or the rest of your code, so I'm just taking a stab in the dark. In the meantime, take a look at some of the suggestions I submitted below.

Comment: @Paul Nevermind. I mean, i can just use the session instead of repeating the whole code again when i'm not using any other data than the UserType. Silly me. Probably i'm just confused. But what makes me curious is what's wrong with the while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just gathered all the sources and tested your HTML locally. I'm getting some errors, so I suggest changing your code to this:

**index.php** (Moved JS code beneath jQuery and Bootstrap script tags)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<?php
    require_once 'session.php';
    require_once 'connection.php';
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Nav Sidebar</title>
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="bootstrap/css/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include 'header/header.php'; ?>

        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var change = true;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function () {
                    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
                });
            });

            function toggle_caret() {
                $("#caret1").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-down", change);
                $("#caret1").toggleClass("glyphicon-chevron-left", !change);
                change = !change
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**header.php** (Removed the database code, since that seemed to be the root of your problem)

```
<?php
$UType = $_SESSION['UserType'];

if($UType == "USER")
{
    include 'header_user.php';
}
else if ($UType == "SUPERIOR")
{
    include 'header_superior.php';
}
else if ($UType == "ADMIN")
{
    include 'header_admin.php';
}
else
{ 
    die("Not a Valid User Type.");
}
?>
```

**header_user.php** (Adding missing closing `div` tag)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Dashboard<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li onclick="toggle_caret()"><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sub1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Requisition<small><span style="float:right" id="caret1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></small></a>
                </li>
                <ul class="nav collapse" id="sub1">
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Form</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Status</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Approved</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Rejected</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;In Process</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Search</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What errors did u get? Since i don't get any :O and my html works fine on my localhost

Comment: I added descriptions of the functional changes. Anything else I changed was just for consistency with your programming style. Good luck!

Comment: Okay. The reason why i load the JS code at the end of the page is because from what i know, it will load faster. But since i'm just a beginner, thanks for your advices :)

Comment: Really, you just want to load your external scripts after your HTML. The code you wrote is dependent on jQuery, so it throws an error when it's loaded before the library.

Comment: Well, it's weird cuz i can run the code without any error eventhough the libraries were loaded at the end of the page :\

Comment: It did for me. The error wasn't fatal, but you might as well make everything correct while you're making changes.

Comment: Well i followed that from bootstrap page. I mean both the libraries are for bootstrap. U can take a look at this link http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/ and look at their index.php on the very end of the pages :|